# ¿Como puedo detectar que ya existe una palabra en mi HTML con js?

Tags: javascript, html

En mi página tengo varios productos, cada uno con su respectivo botón de agregar al carrito, cuando se le da click a ese botón se abre un cuadro con una lista de los productos que van siendo agregados done dice su nombre, su cantidad y su precio.
El problema es que se si vuelvo a agregar el mismo producto este se repite en la lista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en vez de eso quiero que aumente la cantidad,es decir si antes decia "producto x, cantidad 1" quiero que diga "producto x cantidad 2" pero que no se repita. Entonces necesito un metodo, una condicional para detectar si un producto ya esta agregado en mi lista

Aqui aLgo de codigo:

```js
let lista_de_productos = document.querySelector(".lista_de_productos");
carrito_btn = document.querySelectorAll(".btn_carrito");

for (cada_btn_carrito of carrito_btn) {
    let precio_c = cada_btn_carrito.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("p").innerHTML;
    let nombre_c = cada_btn_carrito.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("h3 a").innerHTML;

    cada_btn_carrito.onclick = () => { 
       
    lista_de_productos.innerHTML +=
    ` <li>
        <div class='nombre_p_list w-50'>${nombre_c}</div>
        <input type='text' name='' value='1'>
        <span class='mx-3 cerrar_lista'>x</span>
        <span class='list_price'>${precio_c}</span>
    </li> `

    }
}
```

```html
 <!-- el producto ----->
 <article class="producto">
    <a href="http://"><img src="img/miProducto.jpg"></a>
    <h3><a href="http://">titulo de mi producto</a></h3>
    <p class="precio">$325.00</p>
    <i class="btn_carrito">mi boton carrito</i>
</article>

<!-- la lista ----------->
<form class="lista_carrito">
    <div class="text-right">
        <span class="">x</span>
    </div>
    <ul class=" lista_de_productos list-unstyled border mx-2">
      <!-- aqui agrego las listas con javascript -->
     </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Veo que directamente recoges el nombre, el precio y lo colocas a la lista del carrito, seria mejor que guardes todos los productos que el cliente elija en un arreglo y que cada elemento tuviera un ID para que con un condicional pudieras saber si se repite el elemento y a ese elemento solo adicionarle el precio del producto.

Aquí un ejemplo de como podrías hacerlo: 
**Lo he publicado en codepen para que lo puedas entender mejor***
https://codepen.io/tekendaniel/pen/xvVqdZ

```js
 /* js archivo*/
    let lista_de_productos = document.querySelector(".lista_de_productos");
    let carrito_btn = document.querySelectorAll(".btn_carrito");
    
    let productos_seleccionados = []
    let arrayProductos =[]
    let cantidad_c = 1
    
    let addProducto = (event) => {
      
      lista_de_productos.innerHTML =''
      idProducto = event.currentTarget.parentElement.id
    
          /*Verifica si el id ya se encuentra en la lista, si no es así lo agrega al array productos_seleccionados*/
      
          if(arrayProductos.indexOf(idProducto)<0)
            {
                arrayProductos.push(idProducto)
                productos_seleccionados.push({
                                                    producto:idProducto, 
                                                    cantidad: cantidad_c
                                                })
            }
         else
            {
                for(let product of productos_seleccionados)
                  {
                      if(product['producto'] == idProducto)
                        {
                            product['cantidad'] += 1
                        }
                  }
                
             }
    
    
      for(let element of productos_seleccionados){
        
              let nombre_c = document.querySelector(`#${element['producto']} h3 a`).innerHTML   
              let precio_c = parseFloat(document.querySelector(`#${element['producto']} .precio`).innerHTML).toFixed(2)
    
              lista_de_productos.innerHTML += `<li id='carrito_${element}'>
                                    <div class='nombre_p_list w-50'>${nombre_c}</div>
                                    <input type='text' name='' value='${element['cantidad']}'>
                                    <span class='mx-3 cerrar_lista'>x</span>
                                    <span class='list_price'>${precio_c}</span>
                                    </li>`
            
            
       
        
          }
    
    
    
    }
    
    carrito_btn.forEach(boton => {
        boton.addEventListener("click", addProducto);
    })
```

```html
<!-- los productos ----->
     <article class="producto" id="P12">
        <a href="http://"><img src="img/miProducto.jpg"></a>
        <h3><a href="http://">Zapatos</a></h3>
        <p class="precio">325.00</p>
        <i class="btn_carrito">mi boton carrito</i>

    </article>

     <article class="producto" id="P13">
        <a href="http://"><img src="img/miProducto.jpg"></a>
        <h3><a href="http://">Polos</a></h3>
        <p class="precio">325.00</p>
        <i class="btn_carrito">mi boton carrito</i>

    </article>


     <article class="producto" id="P14">
        <a href="http://"><img src="img/miProducto.jpg"></a>
        <h3><a href="http://">Pantalon</a></h3>
        <p class="precio">325.00</p>
        <i class="btn_carrito">mi boton carrito</i>

    </article>

     <article class="producto" id="P15">
        <a href="http://"><img src="img/miProducto.jpg"></a>
        <h3><a href="http://">Gorra</a></h3>
        <p class="precio">325.00</p>
        <i class="btn_carrito">mi boton carrito</i>

    </article>
    
    <!-- la lista ----------->
    <form class="lista_carrito">
        <div class="text-right">
            <span class="">Lista de productos seleccionados</span>
        </div>
        <ul class="lista_de_productos list-unstyled border mx-2">
          <!-- aqui agrego las listas con javascript -->
         </ul>
    </form>
```

Comment: Me podrias explicar como hacer esa condicional con el id?

Comment: Si no puedes ver bien el código te dejo un enlace de codepen https://codepen.io/tekendaniel/pen/xvVqdZ

Comment: Aquí dice que evite comentarios tipo "gracias" pero es que eres un crack!. Dure como una hora para entender todo el codigo porque no soy muy pro pero todavía hay algo:  `lista_de_productos.innerHTML =''`  No sé que logramos con eso.

Comment: Con `lista_de_productos.innerHTML =''"`  borras todo el html dentro del `<ul class="lista_de_productos">codigo</ul>` que incluyes cada vez que haces click en el botón de carrito así se evita que se valla acumulando y solo muestre los datos que hay en array